# UDP network stuck while system waiting/receiving data

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

I have to build up a bilateral UDP network system, that means both server and client send and receive data, as illustrated by the below diagram:

[image: network diagram]

I took a ready to use example from 
http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-winsock/

However, on the client, when a data(string) is sent, the client gets stuck waiting for incoming data on this line:
`recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)`

The client cannot send more data until it receives incoming data.

Is there any method that I can keep sending data to the server, while also waiting for incoming data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because by default sockets are blocking, which means `recv` and `read` family calls will hang until there is data available. You need to either use nonblocking I/O with multiplexing like `select()` or `poll()`, or use a separate, dedicated thread for receiving data.

Nonblocking I/O is significantly different in design from blocking I/O code, so there's not a simple change you can make. I recommend you read something like [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#advanced) which covers all of these issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helps me  a lot. Does that mean Nonblocking I/O  can also be constructed under UDP structure? I appreciate.

Comment: @ShinChenHu Yes, nonblocking I/O can be done with any kind of socket, UDP or TCP. Look up examples for "Nonblocking UDP server in C" for your your operating system. Beej's Guide that I linked has an example for Linux and a note on making the programs work on Windows.